how to edit a paragraph using aspose-words for python
I'm trying to edit the paragraph text from a document. But only the different words, not the whole paragraph. How can I do that?
def edit_paragraph(docPath, paragraph_to_find, new_paragraph_text):
    # Cargar el documento
    doc = aw.Document(docPath)

    # Activar el seguimiento de cambios (track changes)
    doc.start_track_revisions("author", date.today())

    doc.range.replace(paragraph_to_find, new_paragraph_text)

    # Guardar el documento con los cambios
    new_doc_path = docPath.split(".docx")[0] + "_edited.docx"
    doc.save(new_doc_path)

    return new_doc_path

Every help will be appreciated.
expected output

Could you please elaborate the question in more details. In your code you replace paragraph_to_find with new_paragraph_text text in the whole document. It would be great if you provide input and expected output documents. This will allow to better understand your requirements. Also, I would suggest to post the question in Aspose.Words support forum: https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8/
